Выводятся не все элементы коллекции children определенного узла
Есть тег формы с его содержимым. Когда нажимается кнопка Subscribe, после инпута появляется див с текстом, к которому надо добавить определенный класс. Я хотела отловить его с помощью form.children и цикла for of, но при выводе появляются только два первоначальных элемента (инпут и кнопка), а дива нет, хотя, если вызвать form.children, он показывает, что див есть. Помогите, пожалуйста, как отловить див?
<form action="#" method="post" class="footer__form">
   <input
   required
   type="email"
   class="input input_subscribe"
   placeholder="Your email"
   />
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn_subscribe">
   Subscribe now
   </button>
</form>

const formSubscribe = document.querySelector('.footer__form');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn_subscribe');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(formSubscribe.children);
  for(let i of formSubscribe.children) {
     console.log(i)
}
 
})


Покажите скрипт, который добавляет div

Ты неправильно проверяешь - поэтому кажется что, элемент есть во время обработчика клика, на самом деле - это не так

@Grundy А как надо проверять?

Посмотри в дубликате, почему это происходит. Ты можешь попробовать вывести length - и увидеть, что в момент вывода внутри формы еще два элемента, а не три
